# Texture glitch edit/object mode?

Tags: uv

How do I fix this?
In edit mode unwraped texture displays correctly, but in object mode it looks diffrent.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Please clarify what "*weird stuff*" weird stuff you refer to and how you setup your scene.

Comment: shape keys, subdivision sufrrface, hidden faces, or hidden objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh, I just had an unaplied decimate modifier..
Hope this helps If you others have similar problem